# Is there a way to timeout a subrequest after a set amount of time on a nginx server using the lua-nginx-module?

Tags: nginx, timer, lua

I need to make a subrequest but I don't want it to take longer than 250ms.  Is there a way to have the subrequest time itself out after 250ms and return 204 error?